# User asks twice and the second time the user gets different answer?

Tags: java, xcode, java.util.scanner, computer-science

Well, my code is a little bit long so I just put the first part when you see x ==1 part actually it has seven parts like this. My aim is like you chose 1A and it gives you the table (that part I did it.) What I want is if the user writes 1A again the system must say sorry. How can I do this without using any packages?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class deneme{
    public  void printTable(String [ ][ ] seat){
        for(int r=0; r<seat.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c< seat[0].length; c++){
                System.out.print(seat[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
    deneme k = new deneme();
       String [][] seat = {{"1","A","B","C","D"},{"2","A","B","C","D"},{"3","A","B","C","D"},{"4","A","B","C","D"},{"5","A","B","C","D"},{"6","A","B","C","D"},{"7","A","B","C","D"}};
     Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
     int x = 6;
     String s;
     String d;

        while(x <= 7){
            System.out.println("Please choose your seat number (1 to 7).But if you want to terminate the program please write 0");
            s = read.nextLine();
            x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println("Please choose your seat row (A to D)");
            d = read.nextLine();







        if(x == 1){
            if((d.equals("A")|| d.equals("a"))){
                seat[0][1] = "X";
                k.printTable(seat);

            }

            else if((d.equals("B")|| d.equals("b")) ){
                seat[0][2] = "X";
                System.out.println("Your seat is chosen ");
                k.printTable(seat);


            }

            else if((d.equals("C")|| d.equals("c")) ){
                seat[0][3] = "X";
                System.out.println(" Your seat is chosen ");
                k.printTable(seat);

            }

            else if((d.equals("D")|| d.equals("d")) ){
                seat[0][4] = "X";
                System.out.println(" Your seat is chosen " );
                k.printTable(seat);

            }


        }
```

Comment: Note: `d.equalsIgnoreCase("A")` might be easier.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not needing any package. But... maaaaaaybe consider checking to see if the seat position already has an `X` before just blindly writing an `X` to it? (which is what you're currently doing). *(of course, there's quite a bit you can do to get rid of all the repetitive code, but that's not in the scope of your question)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning "X" to seat[0][1], you can check if it is already "X". Then, you can print "Sorry"

```
if(x == 1)
    {
         if((d.equals("A")|| d.equals("a")))
         {
            if(seat[0][1].equals("X"))
            {
            //Print Sorry
            }
           else
            {
              seat[0][1] = "X";
              k.printTable(seat);
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It is a very easy solution how I can forget this I mean I tried every possibility using while such as but ok it works :D

Comment: Note that this is the exact solution I mentioned in my answer, aside from writing the code for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of stuff you can do to clean up your code, but... specifically to your question, you're never checking to see if `seat[x][y]` already has an `"X"` in it before writing an `"X"` to it.

If you perform a simple if-check on the value of the array, and it already equals `"X"`, you can then print your message instead of writing to the array (and possibly overwriting a previously-chosen seat selection).

Comment: but then how can i do it without using an array (I am begginer in java by the way)

Comment: Doing it without an array? That wasn't part of your question. And that's too broad - lots of ways to do it.

Comment: yes it was not part of my question , I am just curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Map` data structure (holds the data as key-value pair) to store which seats have been already booked.

You can refer the below steps for solving your problem using `Map`:

(1) When the user inputs the seat-number, check if it exists in the `Map` object

(2) If it exists, ie., already booked then show an error message

(3) If it doesn't exist, then allow the user to book and store it in Map

I have provided pseudocode code below which uses `Map`:

```
public class Deneme {

    private static Map<String, String> seatsUsed = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //add other code here

        while(x <= 7){

          //add other code here

       if(seatsUsed.get(x+d) != null) {
           System.out.println(" Sorry, seat alrady booked");
        }

       if(x == 1){
            if((d.equals("A")|| d.equals("a"))){
                seat[0][1] = "X";
                k.printTable(seat);
                seatsUsed.put(x+d, "Y");//Y indicates that booked
       }

      //add other code

      }
    }
```

Also, as a side note, you have got lots of issues with your code as mentioned below:

(1) Follow Java naming conventions Class names starts with uppercase

(2) Your code is hard to follow, try to refactor into smaller methods

(3) Use existing `String`/other API methods effectively like you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of writing `d.equals("A")|| d.equals("a")`